# Bootstrap Apps Script Form Mail Notification based on field submitted

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

I have built a Bootstrap form in Apps Script that sends the answers to a Google Spreadsheet.
Now, I would that when in a dropdown a user select a specific option, the form send the notification to specific mail address. In the specific case, the dropdown with "id=area".

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
    }
    
    /* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
    function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
          .getContent();
    }
    
    /* @Process Form */
    function processForm(formObject) {
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx/edit#gid=0";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
      
      ws.appendRow([formObject.nome_cognome,
                    formObject.mail,
                    formObject.telefono,
                    formObject.sede,
                    formObject.area,
                    formObject.tipo,
                    formObject.durata]);
    }
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="durata"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: moment().add(3, 'day'),
    startDate: moment(),
    endDate: moment().add(5, 'day'),
    fromLabel: ('From'),
    timePicker24Hour: (true),
    locale: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
    }
  });
});

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-8">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label for="nome_cognome">Nome e Cognome<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_cognome" name="nome_cognome" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label for="mail">Indirizzo E-Mail<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label for="telefono">Telefono<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sede">In servizio presso (indicare sede)<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="sede" name="sede" required="">
                                <option>--Seleziona--</option>
                                <option>Rome</option>
                                <option>Napoli</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="area">Area<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="area" name="area" required="">
                                <option>--Seleziona--</option>
                                <option>Marketing</option>
                                <option>Amministrazione</option>
                                <option>Direzione</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tipo">Tipo di permesso<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="tipo" name="tipo" required="">
                                <option>--Seleziona--</option>
                                <option>Ferie</option>

                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col">
                                <label for="durata">Durata<em class="required">*</em></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="durata" id="durata" required="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Invia richiesta</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an email when `formObject.area` is the specific option.

In this case, how about modifying the function of `processForm`?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
ws.appendRow([formObject.nome_cognome,
              formObject.mail,
              formObject.telefono,
              formObject.sede,
              formObject.area,
              formObject.tipo,
              formObject.durata]);
```

To:

```
ws.appendRow([formObject.nome_cognome,
              formObject.mail,
              formObject.telefono,
              formObject.sede,
              formObject.area,
              formObject.tipo,
              formObject.durata]);

// I added below script.
var specificOption = "Marketing";  // Please set the specific option you want to use.
if (formObject.area == specificOption) {
  var specificEmailAddress = "###";  // Please set the specific email address you want to use.
  var subject = "###";  // Please set the subject of email.
  var body = "###";  // Please set the subject of body.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(specificEmailAddress, subject, body);
  // You can also use this. MailApp.sendEmail(specificEmailAddress, subject, body);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)
- [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

Comment: Perfect! How can I put in the body of the mail also the data of the fields submitted using a HTML template?

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the data of the fields submitted using a HTML template`. For example, if you want to include `formObject` in the email, how about modifying `var body = "###";` to `var body = JSON.stringify(formObject);`? But I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your new question. So if that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: If you see the form, there are some fields, name, telephone... how I can put in the notification mail (body, subject) also these information submitted by the user?

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. Can I ask you whether my understanding for your new question in my replying is correct? Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about it. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Yes. It could also be good in the body of the mail use a template HTML.

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But in that case, can you post it as new question by including the result you expect? Because from your comment, I couldn't still understand about the detail of your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. When you post it as new question, it will help users including me think of the solution. How about this? If you can cooperate ro resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Simply I would like to send a mail confirmation in HTML format... What is not clear?

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But from `Simply I would like to send a mail confirmation in HTML format... What is not clear? `, I cannot understand about the result you expect. And also, your new question is different from your this question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad.